# Getting error while installing LLVM Ubuntu nightly packages

Tags: linux, ubuntu, llvm, ubuntu-16.04

I have Ubuntu 16.04 server and want to install LLVM packages there.
I run `bash -c "$(wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh)"` command from https://apt.llvm.org, but get an error

```
Err:32 https://apt.llvm.org/xenial llvm-toolchain-xenial-14/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Fetched 200 kB in 2s (89.5 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://apt.llvm.org/xenial llvm-toolchain-xenial-14 Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://apt.llvm.org/xenial/dists/llvm-toolchain-xenial-14/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch https://apt.llvm.org/xenial/dists/llvm-toolchain-xenial-14/main/binary-all/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Now I can't even run `sudo apt-get update` and get the very same error.
How can I fix this or revert back?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [LLVM website](https://apt.llvm.org/), [16.04 reached EOL in 2021](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPOpN.png), so packages from the LLVM source were disabled.

I'd recommend updating to LTS.